# pushbullet line break problem with VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, sms, pushbullet

i made a userform in VBA Excel to send SMS via Pushbullet to my clients it works perfectly when i send a single line message , but when i try to send multiple line message it doesn't work,i searched in stackoverflow and google with no answer , i need some help
the code i'm using is:

```
Private Sub smsfac_Click()
Dim lastrow As Integer
'Activate "Microsoft XML, v6.0" under Tools > References
If Me.sms_client.value = "" Or Me.sms_nmbr.value = "" Or Me.sms_txt.value = "" Then
Me.smsfac.ForeColor = vbRed
Me.smsfac.BorderColor = vbRed
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
Me.smsfac.ForeColor = &HFFFF00
Me.smsfac.BorderColor = &H80000006
Else
Dim item As ListItem
Dim ACCESS_TOKEN As String
Dim TARGET_DEVICE_IDEN As String

'Authentication & Target Device ID
ACCESS_TOKEN = calcule.Range("C7").value
TARGET_DEVICE_IDEN = """" & calcule.Range("C8").value & """"

'Get last row number

'Clear Status
     
    'Get receiver number & text message
    receiver_number = """" & Me.sms_nmbr.Text & """"
    text_message = """" & Me.sms_txt.Text & """"

    'Use XML HTTP
    Set Request = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    
    'Specify Target URL
    URL = "https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/texts"
    
    'Open Post Request
    
    Request.Open "Post", URL, False
    
    'Request Header
    Request.setRequestHeader "Access-Token", ACCESS_TOKEN
    Request.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    
    'Concatenate PostData
    postData = "{""data"":{""target_device_iden"":" & TARGET_DEVICE_IDEN & ",""addresses"":[" & receiver_number & "],""message"":" & text_message & "}}"
    
    'Send the Post Data
    Request.send postData

End If
End Sub
```

also if there's away to the a notification that the SMS was sent or not that will help me alot ,  I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

String values in JSON need quotes - you do not have quotes around `text_message`

```vb
postData = "{""data"":{""target_device_iden"":" & TARGET_DEVICE_IDEN & _
    ",""addresses"":[" & receiver_number & "],""message"":""" & text_message & """}}"
```

EDIT:
See here for how to handle line breaks in message text:
[Pushbullet pycurl with linefeed in message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537481/pushbullet-pycurl-with-linefeed-in-message)

```vb
postData = "{""data"":{""target_device_iden"":" & TARGET_DEVICE_IDEN & _
    ",""addresses"":[" & receiver_number & "]," & _
     """message"":""" & replace(text_message, vbLf, "\n") & """}}"
```

If you're still having problems, then try using Debug.Print to output `postData` and check it looks as you expect.

EDIT2:  if the textbox uses vbCrLf as a line break then try

```vb
text_message = Replace(Me.sms_txt.Text, vbCrLf, vbLf)
text_message = Replace(text_message , vbLf, "\n")

postData = "{""data"":{""target_device_iden"":" & TARGET_DEVICE_IDEN & _
    ",""addresses"":[" & receiver_number & "]," & _
     """message"":""" & text_message & """}}"
```

Soory I missed you were adding the quotes when you read the value from the textbox - my bad not reading the whole code and just jumping to `postData`

Comment: thanks for the replay Tim but when i tried this even a single lined sms won't be sent , the old one works but only with single line , if i used multiline textbox the client won't recieve any text

Comment: I don't know why you're having a problem, but string values in JSON do need to be quoted.  That's part of the spec.

Comment: yes you're right but i already put
 text_message = """" & Me.sms_txt.value & """"

Comment: debug.print postdata it gives me
{"data":{"target_device_iden":"ujCxgKp8qDQsjA2NhFOs2u","addresses":["0555558711"],"message":"Introduction

\n 

\nSecond Line of Text

\n Third Line of Text"}}

Comment: What response do you get from the API when you send that?

Comment: when its one line i get :  Status Code: 200

Comment: when i try multiline it gives me: Status Code: 400 | Status Text: {"error":{"code":"invalid_request","type":"invalid_request","message":"Failed to decode JSON body.","cat":"(=^‥^=)"},"error_code":"invalid_request"}

Comment: when i tried your code , but the message in a sheet.cell it worked

Comment: i think the problem when i get it from a textbox

Comment: Maybe the textbox uses vbCrLf as a linebreak?

Comment: thank you Tim , the vbcrlf helped me now my problem is solved

Comment: Good to hear we got there eventually.